# Dynamically Writing Javascript to a new HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code below in which I am using to attempt to dynamically write some javascript into a new html page at the click of a button.

I am however getting an error when attempting to do so I get "unterminated string constamnt"
in theory, this should work:

```
var html     =  '<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
html    +=  '<html>\n'
html    +=  '<head>\n'
html    +=  '<script type="text/javascript">\n'
html    +=  'function testme() {\n'
html    +=  'alert("the test worked!")\n'
html    +=  '}\n'       
html    +=  '</script>\n'
html    +=  '</head>\n'
html    +=  '<body>\n'
html    +=  '</body>\n'
html    +=  '</html\n'

window.open('','').document.write(html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing > on the last line

```
html    +=  '</html\n'  <-- Missing a greater than
```

should be

```
html    +=  '</html>\n'
```

If the code is inline and not in an external script, you will need to break up the closing script tag.

```
html    +=  '</scr' + + 'ipt>\n';
```

also, use semicolons.

Now the window.open, document.write line looks strange. Most developers would write it as

```
var winPop = window.open('','');
winPop.document.open();
winPop.document.write(html);
winPop.document.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip you can use multiple lines instead of putting `html +=` on every line just add a backslash at the end of a line so:

```
html = '<html>\n  \
        <head>\n \
        <script type="text/javascript">\n \
            function testme() {\n \
                alert("the test worked!")\n \
            }\n \
        </script>\n \
        </head>\n \
        <body>\n \
        </body>\n \
        </html>\n  ';
```

However you there were some flaws in your code you forgot the `>` for the `</html>` 
And just like **epascarello** said break up the script tag.

However you might want to take a look at if you want to open a different html document with your popup, or even a php file since then you could just pickup the `$_GET` values and fill your custom values in with that. what would be more reliable.

[Check out the w3c about $_GET](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp)