# Cannot get function to work when the page is written dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get alert to run, after the new page is written dynamically from a click of a button from the host page.

The new page loads, but nothing happens.

```
function test2() {

var html     =  '<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
html    +=  '<html>\n'
html    +=  '<head>\n'
html    +=  '<script type="text/javascript">\n'
html    +=  'window.onload = function() {\n'
html    +=  'alert("the test worked!")\n'
html    +=  '}\n'       
html    +=  '</scr' + + 'ipt>\n';
html    +=  '</head>\n'
html    +=  '<body>\n'
html    +=  '</body>\n'
html    +=  '</html\n'

window.open('','').document.write(html)

}
```

Comment: `html    +=  '</scr' + + 'ipt>\n';` is a syntax error.

Comment: this avoids an "unterminated string constant" error Chad

Comment: same question as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237630/dynamically-writting-javascript-to-a-new-html-page/13238127#13238127

Comment: @Jason Kelly then you have another issue, because this will give you unexpected results. `var html = ''; html += '</scr' + + 'ipt>\n';` will yield `"</scrNaN"` or a syntax error in some cases. Your "unterminated string constant" is from something else (probably a lack of semicolons).

Comment: It's a typo in epascarello's answer to your previous question. The correct form is `'</scr' + 'ipt>\n'` , or shorter `'<\/script>\n'`. You maybe want to take a look at the end of his answer too =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens, because you're not closing the newly created document. If you take a good look to your browser, you'll notice, that it's still loading. Corrected code (useless `\n`s omitted):

```
function test2 () {
    var win,
        html = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    html += '<html>';
    html += '<head>';
    html += '<script type="text/javascript">';
    html += 'window.onload = function () {';
    html += 'alert("the test worked!");';
    html += '}';
    html += '<\/script>';
    html += '</head>';
    html += '<body>';
    html += '</body>';
    html += '</html>';
    win = window.open('','');
    win.document.write(html);
    win.document.close();
    return;
}
```

As you can see, you need a reference to the newly created window, so you can close its document. And please, always use semicolons, they make your code more readable, and save you from many harms in some situations when they really are needed.

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to trying to add a script with `innerHTML`: it just doesn't work.

Instead, you will need to create a `<script>` tag with `document.createElement`, then append it to the body of the window.

Comment: This is far too advanced for me, how do you do this =S

Comment: Check out the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement).